# testing membership provider lock user method

Tags: c#, tdd, asp.net-membership

this is probably fairly basic question. I'm learning membership provider and tdd so here it is. I want to read maxpasswordattempts from my app.config and used that value to lock user for lets say 30 min after incorrect password attempts.

**subquestion**
How to read data stored in app.config and use in bellow test code

Example using tdd should be great. something like
**Question**

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanLockUserAfterIncorrectPassowrdAttempts()
{

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [pgProvider](https://code.google.com/p/pgprovider/) implementation I wrote; it has unit tests supporting max bad login attempts.

(Specifically, [this test fixture](https://code.google.com/p/pgprovider/source/browse/trunk/pgProvider.Tests/MembershipProvider/SecurityFeatures.cs))

Comment: ok, this is exactly what I need, and how to read maxInvalidPasswordAttempts from app.config in tests?

Comment: You don't want to read it from the app.config in tests; then you can't test different values and configurations.  Use something like the `config` object in the test setup method.  That is the same mechanism the membership provider system uses when reading from the app/web.config.